# Pass "Wb" to Sub

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way how to pass String or maybe some other type of data
to Sub() and based on that String, define and open new WorkBook?

For Example

```
Sub main()
   Call workbook_generator("Wb1")
End Sub

Sub workbook_generator(name As String)
   Dim name as Workbook
   Set name = Workbooks.Add
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "define?"? Do you need opening **an existing workbook**, knowing its full name (the string in discussion), or its pas and part of the name? Do you wan adding a new workbook and name it according to the mentioned `String` and saved in a path you know? Something as `ThisWorlbook.path`...

Comment: so when you defines  "Dim Wb1 as WorkBook"
i wanted to type to make that "Wb1" dynamical so i can manually give some other value
instead of  "Wb1"

Sub workbook_generator(name As String)
would do the line  "Dim name as Workbook".

But i solved it by adding Wb1, Wb2, Wb3, Wb4 into another module as Public
and changed sub to look like this  Sub workbook_generator(name As Workbook)
and calling sub with  "Call workbook_generator(Wb1)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the workbook object if you want to reuse it.
I added the option to pass the fullfilename as well ...

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim fullfilename As String
fullfilename = "D:\file1.xlsx"

Dim wb As Workbook
workbook_generator wb, fullfilename

wb.Worksheets(1).Name = "testsheet"
End Sub

Public Sub workbook_generator(ByRef wb As Workbook, Optional fullfilename As String)

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
If fullfilename <> vbNullString Then
    'you should put a check here if folder exists
    'or at least an error handler
    wb.SaveAs fullfilename
End If

End Sub
```